# Trying to speed up finding an index in active record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

I have a page where I start with a list of `check_ins` or client visits and then I need to loop through each visit (`i`) to find all that client's other visits to determine the visits neighbor (`i - 1`).  I need to pull information from that visits neighbor as well. This is taking a very long time and I thought there might be a speedier way to perform the query.

Assuming I start with the list of visits or `check_ins`:

```
check_ins.each_with_index do |ci, i|

  # access the client
  client = ci.client 

  # pull other relevent client visits
  client_cis = client.check_ins
    .visible
    .includes(:weigh_in)
    .select(:id, :week, :created_at, :type_of_weighin)
    .where.not(check_ins: {type_of_weighin: nil})
    .where.not(weigh_ins: {id: nil})
    .where("weigh_ins.date >= ?", ci.created_at - 3.weeks) 

  # access the visit's index
  i = client_cis.index(ci)

  # access the visit's neighbor
  neighbor = client_cis[ i - 1 ]

  # perform downstream calculations using visit and it's neighbor
  ...

end
```

Is there a faster way to perform this type of analysis?

Comment: You could first focus on getting rid of the loop, that way you're making the query once for every element in `check_ins`.

Comment: @engineersmnky definitely agree with the `each_with_index`, that was left over from something else.  The `check_ins` have a default ordering so I do know the neighbor.  I had used a `join` rather than `.where.not(weigh_ins: {id: nil})` but thought that was slower.

Comment: I need the `weigh_in` data

Comment: If I loop through the clients, how do I access the `check_in` and it's `weigh_in` and the neighbor?  Wouldn't I need another query regardless?

Comment: yeah, that makes sense.  I will say I really appreciate the thought you gave the problem and the solution you had posted with the `id: [check_ins.pluck(:client_id)]` was very clever!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this although I make no performance improvement guarantees the following should result in the same functional mechanism

```
grouped_check_ins = check_ins.group_by(&:client_id)
weigh_ins_table = WeighIn.arel_table
check_ins_table = CheckIn.arel_table 
weigh_ins_join = Arel::Nodes::InnerJoin.new(
  weigh_ins_table,weigh_ins_table.create_on(
   weigh_ins_table[:check_in_id].eq(check_ins_table[:id]).and(
     weigh_ins_table[:date].gteq(
       check_ins_table[:created_at] - Arel.sql("interval '3 week'")
     ) 
    )
  )
)
Client
  .joins(:check_ins)
  .joins(weigh_ins_join)
  .eager_load(check_ins: :weigh_in)
  .where(id: grouped_check_ins.keys) # alternately .where(id: check_ins.select(:client_id))
  .where.not(check_ins: {type_of_weighin: nil})
  .each do |client|
    client_check_ins_with_neighbor = client.check_ins.each_cons(2)
       .select do |_,b| 
         grouped_check_ins[client.id].any? {|c| c.id == b.id }
       end 
    client_check_ins_with_neighbor.each do |neighbor,check_in| 
       # perform downstream calculations using visit and it's neighbor
    end  
  end
```

**UPDATE** to explain what this code does per the OP's request:

- `grouped_check_ins = check_ins.group_by(&:client_id)` - group your `CheckIn` objects by the client_id for faster lookup. This results in a `Hash` of `{client_id => [CheckIns]}`
- Arel work - This is so we can build a join with multiple conditions. In this case the conditions are "weigh_ins.check_in_id = check_ins.id AND weigh_ins.date >= check_ins.created_at - interval '3 week'"

```
weigh_ins_table = WeighIn.arel_table
check_ins_table = CheckIn.arel_table 
weigh_ins_join = Arel::Nodes::InnerJoin.new(
  weigh_ins_table,weigh_ins_table.create_on(
   weigh_ins_table[:check_in_id].eq(check_ins_table[:id]).and(
     weigh_ins_table[:date].gteq(
       check_ins_table[:created_at] - Arel.sql("interval '3 week'")
     ) 
    )
  )
)
```

- Build the Query

```
Client
  .joins(:check_ins)
  .joins(weigh_ins_join)
  .eager_load(check_ins: :weigh_in)
  .where(id: grouped_check_ins.keys) # alternately .where(id: check_ins.select(:client_id))
  .where.not(check_ins: {type_of_weighin: nil})
```

This results in SQL akin to

```
SELECT 
/* every column from each table listed 
with names generated by rails so that it can 
perform eager loading appropriately */ 
FROM 
  clients
  INNER JOIN check_ins ON check_ins.client_id = clients.id 
  INNER JOIN weigh_ins ON weigh_ins.check_in_id = check_ins.id 
    AND weigh_ins.date >= check_ins.created_at - interval '3 week'
WHERE 
  clients.id IN (/* list of client_ids from the group_by */) 
AND check_ins.type_of_weighin IS NOT NULL
```

- Iterate over the clients check ins in consecutive order, 2 at a time. Select each pair where the second item is in the list of client check ins originally provided.

```
client_check_ins_with_neighbor = client.check_ins.each_cons(2)
  .select do |_,b| 
    grouped_check_ins[client.id].any? {|c| c.id == b.id }
end
```

- Then we just iterate over those selected pairs to perform whatever work needs to be done

```
client_check_ins_with_neighbor.each do |neighbor,check_in| 
  # perform downstream calculations using visit and it's neighbor
end
```

Comment: This line throws an error as `ci` isn't defined: `.where("weigh_ins.date >= ?", ci.created_at - 3.weeks)`

Comment: @JeremyThomas oops. Updated again (even uglier than before) and I assumed   `WeighIn` belongs_to `CheckIn` which might be incorrect.

Comment: Hmm.. now I'm seeing this: `LINE 1: ..._id" = "check_ins"."id" AND "weigh_ins"."date" >= DATEADD(we...` ... `HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: you are a sql WIZARD.  Would it be asking too much too have you walk through what you did there?  It turned a 30+ second query into one that is less than 0.5 seconds.

Comment: @JeremyThomas Is the result the same? Also I added an explanation and in doing so noticed a small inefficiency so I updated that as well (Filtering the clients table by id rather than the check_ins table by client_id)

Comment: It looks perfect! Thanks for the thorough explanation!